select particular values from nested dictionary-Python
I new at learning Python... I would like to print the description value for each friend:
friends={
    "Rachel":{
        "job":"fashion",
        "last name":"Green",
        "description":"brave for starting life over",
},
    "Monica":{
        "job":"culinary",
        "last name":"Geller",
        "description":"likes things clean",
},
    "Phoebe":{
        "job":"musician/masseuse",
        "last name":"Buffay",
        "description":"somewhat of a question mark",
},
    "Chandler":{
        "job":"statistical analysis and data reconfiguration",
        "last name":"Bing",
        "description":"the funny one",
},
    "Joey":{
        "job":"actor",
        "last name":"Tribbiani",
        "description":"italian american actor, born in queens, 7 sisters, only boy, NY Knicks rule",
},
    "Ross":{
        "job":"dinosaurs",
        "last name":"Geller",
        "description":"academia, being a good father, not knowing when to shut up; 3 divorces",
},
}

I tried this but it printed the names:
friends_keys=[]
for friend in friends:
    friends_keys.append(friend)

print(friends_keys)

What I was expecting is:
brave for starting life over
likes things clean
somewhat of a question mark
the funny one
italian american actor, born in queens, 7 sisters, only boy, NY Knicks rule
academia, being a good father, not knowing when to shut up; 3 divorces


You can get the descriptions with something like: [friend['description'] for friend in friends.values()]

In Python, you should use the dictionary key to access its value. Here's the corrected code:
for i in friends:
    print(friends[i]["description"])

So, to access the value (which is another dictionary), you should use friends[i]. Then, to access the "description" within that dictionary, you use ["description"].

You can avoid the keys of the dictionary altogether, and just focus on the values, like so:
for friend_info in friends.values():
    print(friend_info["description"])


Note that your original code for printing first names:
friends_keys=[]
for friend in friends:
    friends_keys.append(friend)

print(friends_keys)

could be simplified to this:
for first_name in friends.keys():
    print(first_name)

or even shorter:
for first_name in friends:
    print(first_name)

